# Variable and equation in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

For example, imagine, I want to create a rectangle in SVG where the height is equal to *(3*width)^2+width* and add, at the bottom, a circle of radius *width/2* (*cx,cy, r = f( width)*). Everything depends only of one parameter : the rectangle width.
I know it is possible to do it with javascript but I would like something more direct. Is it ccs variable, the only alternative ?
Thanks for answer.

Rq : I read this post ([How do I define or reference a variable in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27812161/7462275)) but it is rather old (from 2015) and it seems the situation has not so much evolved or I googled poorly.

Comment: Please post any try you have done yet?

Comment: @RobertLongson. The tranformation is not linear : height=3*witdh^2+width (for example). And I plan to do things with cosine functions.

Comment: Then I think you need javascript.

Comment: @RobetLongson. Are css (or scss) variables a better way to do that ? https://www.zdnet.com/article/css-to-get-support-for-trigonometry-functions/

Comment: why SVG? this seems pretty easy with CSS only